# How to use Nokogiri to combine multiple like-formatted XML files into CSV

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, concatenation

I want to parse multiple like-formatted XML files into a CSV file.

I searched on Google, nokogiri.org, and on SO but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I have ten XML files in identical format in terms of node/element structure, that reside in the current directory.

After combining the XML files into a single XML file, I need to pull out specific elements of the `advisory` node. I would like to output the `link`, `title`, `location`, `os -> language -> name`, and  `reference -> name` data to the CSV file.

My code  is only able to parse a single XML document and I'd like it to take into account 1:many:

```
# Parse the XML file into a Nokogiri::XML::Document object
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file.xml"))

# Gather the 5 specific XML elements out of the 'advisory' top-level node
data = @doc.search('advisory').map { |adv|
  [
    adv.at('link').content,
    adv.at('title').content,
    adv.at('location').content,
    adv.at('os > language > name').content,
    adv.at('reference > name').content
  ]
}

# Loop through each array element in the object and write out as CSV row
CSV.open('output_file.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  # Explicitly set headers until you figure out how to get them programatically
  csv << ['Link', 'Title', 'Location', 'OS Name', 'Reference Name']
  data.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

I tried changing the code to support multiple XML files and get them into Nokogiri::XML::Document objects:

```
xml_docs = []

Dir.glob("*.xml").each do |file|
  xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.new(file))
  xml_docs << Nokogiri::XML::Document.new(xml)
end
```

This successfully creates an array `xml_docs` with the correct objects it in, but I don't know how to convert these six objects into a single object.

This is sample XML. All XML files use the same node/element structure:

```
<advisories>
  <title> Not relevant </title>
  <customer> N/A </customer>
  <advisory id="12345">
    <link> https://www.google.com </link>
    <release_date>2016-04-07</release_date>
    <title> The Short Description Would Go Here </title>
    <location> Location Name Here </location>
    <os>
      <product>
        <id>98765</id>
        <name>Product Name</name>
      </product>
      <language>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>en</name>
      </language>
    </os>
    <reference>
      <id>00029</id>
      <name>Full</name>
      <area>Not Defined</area>
    </reference>
  </advisory>
  <advisory id="98765">
    <link> https://www.msn.com </link>
    <release_date>2016-04-08</release_date>
    <title> The Short Description Would Go Here </title>
    <location> Location Name Here </location>
    <os>
      <product>
        <id>12654</id>
        <name>Product Name</name>
      </product>
      <language>
        <id>126</id>
        <name>fr</name>
      </language>
    </os>
    <reference>
      <id>00052</id>
      <name>Partial</name>
      <area>Defined</area>
    </reference>
  </advisory>
</advisories>
```

The code leverages Nokogiri::XML::Document but if Nokogiri::XML::Builder will work better for this, I am more than willing to adjust my code accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While it's nice you turned here, unfortunately you missed the point of SO; We help *you* fix mistakes/problems in *your* code. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". We'd like to see evidence of your effort: What did you try? Why didn't it work? If you didn't try, where did you search and why didn't those places have the information you need? Handing us XML and telling us what you want to do smells of you wanting us to write the code to solve the problem, instead of asking us how to solve a problem you encountered as you wrote it.

Comment: I will modify my question shortly with what I've tried. I didn't want to make the question too long but I'll see what I can do.  Thanks for the note!

Comment: You're welcome. SO has an ambitious goal of being an online reference to programming problems, kind of a cookbook of problems and solutions. They're doing well at that, as evidenced by the top-results in the search engines, however it's an ongoing task of making sure the quality of the questions and answers remain high, which is why we want the things we do. Long questions don't mean high quality, so they're hard to write and take forethought and effort, but the end result is great; You get an answer and so do others in the future. Welcome to the battle of solving everyone's problems! :-)

Comment: Good information, thanks!  Editing now-ish with what I've tried and how I'm trying to expand it.

Comment: Hi @theTinMan, does my adjusted question meet all the requirements?  I tried to be as explicit as possible.  Since I'm not getting an error per se, I didn't include any error output.  I've got the code working to a point, but I just don't know how to expand it.  Hope this is better!  Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: That's better. It's not possible to append XML documents together and get a syntactically correct XML document as a result. I'd open the output CSV file, then iterate over the XML documents one-by-one, grab the data desired in each and output it into the CSV file as the data is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd handle the first part, of parsing one XML file, like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<advisories>
  <advisory id="12345">
    <link> https://www.google.com </link>
    <title> The Short Description Would Go Here </title>
    <location> Location Name Here </location>
    <os>
      <language>
        <name>en</name>
      </language>
    </os>
    <reference>
      <name>Full</name>
    </reference>
  </advisory>
  <advisory id="98765">
    <link> https://www.msn.com </link>
    <release_date>2016-04-08</release_date>
    <title> The Short Description Would Go Here </title>
    <location> Location Name Here </location>
    <os>
      <language>
        <name>fr</name>
      </language>
    </os>
    <reference>
      <name>Partial</name>
    </reference>
  </advisory>
</advisories>
EOT
```

Note: This has nodes removed because they weren't important to the question. Please remove fluff when asking as it's distracting.

With this being the core of the code:

```
doc.search('advisory').map{ |advisory|
  link = advisory.at('link').text
  title = advisory.at('title').text
  location = advisory.at('location').text
  os_language_name = advisory.at('os > language > name').text
  reference_name = advisory.at('reference > name').text

  {
    link: link,
    title: title,
    location: location,
    os_language_name: os_language_name,
    reference_name: reference_name
  }
}
```

That could be DRY'd but was written as an example of what to do.

Running that results in an array of hashes, which would be easily output via CSV:

```
# => [
      {:link=>" https://www.google.com ", :title=>" The Short Description Would Go Here ", :location=>" Location Name Here ", :os_language_name=>"en", :reference_name=>"Full"}, 
      {:link=>" https://www.msn.com ", :title=>" The Short Description Would Go Here ", :location=>" Location Name Here ", :os_language_name=>"fr", :reference_name=>"Partial"}
     ]
```

Once you've got that working then fit it into a modified version of your loops to output CSV and read the XML files. This is untested but looks about right:

```
CSV.open('output_file.csv', 'w', 
  headers: ['Link', 'Title', 'Location', 'OS Name', 'Reference Name'],
  write_headers: true
) do |csv|
  Dir.glob("*.xml").each do |file|
    xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(file))
    # parse a file and get the array of hashes
  end

  # pass the array of hashes to CSV for output
end
```

Note that you were using a file mode of `'wb'`. You rarely need `b` with CSV as CSV is supposed to be a text format. If you are *sure* you will encounter binary data then use `'b'` also, but that could lead down a path containing dragons.

Also note that this is using `read`. `read` is not scalable, which means it doesn't care how big a file is, it's going to try to read it into memory, whether or not it'll actually fit. There are lots of reasons to avoid that, but the best is it'll take your program to its knees. If your XML files could exceed the available free memory for your system then you'll want to rewrite using a SAX parser, which Nokogiri supports. How to do that is a different question.

---

> it was actually an Array of array of hashes. I'm not sure how I ended up there but I was easily able to use array.flatten

Meditate on this:

```
foo = []    # => []
foo << [{}] # => [[{}]]
foo.flatten # => [{}]
```

You probably wanted to do this:

```
foo = []    # => []
foo += [{}] # => [{}]
```

Any time I have to use `flatten` I look to see if I can create the array without it being an array of arrays of something. It's not that they're inherently bad, because sometimes they're very useful, but you really wanted an array of hashes so you knew something was wrong and `flatten` was a cheap way out, but using it also costs more CPU time. It's better to figure out the problem and fix it and end up with faster/more efficient code. (And some will say that's a wasted effort or is premature optimization, but writing efficient code is a very good trait and goal.)

Comment: "A path containing dragons"... lol.   I will try this soon.  Thank for for the in-depth explanation !

Comment: Thank you, this works good.  I assigned a variable to each of the `xml.search`'s and wrote those out to a new Array.  Once I had my Array with 6 objects in it, it was actually an Array of array of hashes.  I'm not sure how I ended up there but I was easily able to use `array.flatten` and iterate over the hashes assigning the hash values to the CSV.  Should I post my completed answer?  Btw, I've seen your name many times before--I am glad I get a chance to thank you.  You've helped me and a lot of other people--thank you!

Comment: If you had an array of arrays of hashes you probably didn't concatenate correctly. I'll add an explanation. Don't add your completed answer unless you found the fix; posting your code doesn't help others a lot. My goal is to give back. I've done this stuff a long time, and had a lot of good mentors. I enjoy teaching, mentoring and paying it forward.

Comment: Very helpful again, thanks.  I will play with this in my code until I get it right, but I've continued to keep your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: You were right, using `+=` as opposed to `<<` resulted in the proper array of hashes which did not require the use of `flatten`.  Thanks!!

Comment: Hey the Tin Man, do you by chance know how I'd tackle something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583704/ruby-axlsx-excel-gem-how-to-write-array-to-excel-with-differing-styles-per-c -  it's my follow-up to this question.  Thanks in advance either way!!